# Ensure a user is not able to modify id in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm working on a react/express application. The url look something like this: /dashboard?matchID=2252309 . As a user I should only be able to access this url. if I try to modify the matchid I should not be able to see the page.
Is it a simple way to do this? One option is to create a endpoint and check through my database for access.

Comment: So what is wrong? You must match ID to your entries, if not found - do not show page.

Comment: As a user i have access to ONE matchid - accesses is defined in my database. however i have a page redirecting to the shown url with a matchid depending on which link he has clicked. the entries exist since there are a lot of matches with unique id. I need to make sure that if a user try to write 2252307 instead of 2252309 he gets a warning of some sort.

Comment: You need to match user id also than, so user can see only it's own matches

Comment: store it in an encrypted  token during login

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restricted the user to enter some URL based on your database. To match your expectation you have two available solutions :

**Solution A :**
Check the user's authorization server-side with a web token and restrict the access to the requested ressource. You will have to implement a login and a permission system.

**Solution B :**
Hide your real ressource ID in a web token (JWT) to make a complicated non-deterministic / non-guessable public Id / URL. Anyone who have the exact URL would have access to the requested ressource.